# linux way to convert mp3 stereo to mono?

Tags: audio, mp3

I know how to do it in microsoft windows using Audacity to convert a mp3 audio file from stereo to mono, but it's a few mouse clicks and time consuming if you want to do many.

Is there a program in Linux that provides a way such that I can batch script the commands to convert my folder of some 1000 mp3 files?  For example :

```
some_sound_program.x  --convert-stereo-to-mono  --input file1.mp3  --output file1_mono.mp3
some_sound_program.x  --convert-stereo-to-mono  --input file2.mp3  --output file2_mono.mp3
{and so on}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use ffmpeg:

```
mkdir -p mono ; for i in *.mp3 ; do ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "./$i" -ac 1 -q:a 5 "mono/$i" ; done
```

This will down-mix stereo to mono and re-encode all mp3 files in the current directory.

I do not know if there is a more efficient way without re-encoding e.g. "throw away all channels but one".

Comment: very cool, thanks

Comment: did 1395 mp3's in about 30 minutes, verified singile audio track using audacity in Rocky 8.8 linux; some files had *invalid data found when processing input*.  My mono folder has 1393 files.